# Сравнение int переменной с индексом массива объектов

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть переменная int keys и массив Gameobject-ов (условно возьмем 5 объектов). Мне надо сравнить их, int и индекс массива:

```
int keys;
Gameobject [] Array;

if(keys == "тут индекс массива Array"){
}
```

Такое возможно?

Comment: какой конкретно индекс массива ты хочешь сравнить?

Comment: вроде правильный ответ дали. пять объектов в массиве, индексы от 0 до 4. И каждый индекс сравнить с keys, каждый раз, когда подбирается ключ.

Comment: Но в вопросе-то это непонятно :-) На самом деле то, что в ответе, можно записать одним условием, если перефразировать твой вопрос: как проверить наличие в массиве указанного индекса. `keys >=0 && keys<arr.Length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю вам поможет следующее

```
for(int i =0; i <Array.Length;i++)
{
   if(keys == i)
   {

   }
}
```